# jason has one of the string fields has null and so Jackson parser throws an error

Tags: rest, jackson

JSON string returned by REST API is
{\"Id\":1,\"Name\":\"Test1\",\"Description\":\"Test1 description\",\"ShowInMainScreen\":true,\"CreateDate\":\"2017-12-09T09:55:37\",\"LastUpdateDate\":\"2017-12-09T09:55:37\",\"TrainingsCategories\":null}

My corresponding Java object is

```
    public class TrainingData {
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private int Id;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String Name;
    @JsonProperty("Description")
    private String Description;
    @JsonProperty("ShowInMainScreen")
    private boolean ShowInMainScreen;
    @JsonProperty("CreateDate")
    private String CreateDate;
    @JsonProperty("LastUpdateDate")
    private String LastUpdateDate;
    @JsonProperty("TrainingsCategories")
    private String TrainingsCategories;
```

Following code returns error

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,    false);
    trainingList = mapper.readValue(jsonStringNew, new TypeReference<List<TrainingData>>(){});
```

Error returned is because of TrainingsCategories has null value. If that null is in double quotes then everything works fine. But REST API does not return null with double quote.

Comment: This answers now. trainingCategories is a list and not just a string

Comment: Nulls are perfectly fine for `Collection` valued properties, unless specific configuration decides otherwise (or setter). So you'd need to indicate specific exception message to know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following annotation on your class to resolve your error :

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Exemple with one of my java class, for which I can use null values in json fields.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Module {
  @JsonProperty("name")
        @XmlElement(name="name")
  private String name = null;
```